# JSON WCF Deserialization DataContracts

Tags: c#, json, web-services, wcf, datacontract

I have a `DataContract` that I am attempting to deserialize from some JSON received from a WCF service. I am able to get the root `DeviceID` and `TimeStamp` to deserialize without issue, however, I can not get any of the `GeoLocations` or `Videos` and `VideoFrames` to deserialize.

I have looked around quite a bit and from what I can find this should work. I have tweaked around with some of the `DataContact` attributes quite a bit to try to get this, but still no luck.

I am sending this JSON to a WCF web service.

```
{
    "DeviceId": "74a5f7aa9d4dfd0d",
    "TimeStamp": 1394756724,
    "GeoLocations": [
        {
            "TimeStamp": 1394756724,
            "Latitude": 948.348275,
            "Longitude": 381.3252
        },
        {
            "TimeStamp": 1394756726,
            "Latitude": 98.348275,
            "Longitude": 31.3252
        }
    ],
    "Videos": [
        {
            "VideoFrames": [
                {
                    "TimeStamp": 1234567789,
                    "Base64EncodedFrame": "dajflahfaskfasld"
                },
                {
                    "TimeStamp": 1234567789,
                    "Base64EncodedFrame": "dajflahfaskfasld"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The web service interface looks Like this.

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
    UriTemplate = "json")]
String JSONData();
```

The web service attempts to deserialize the object to this model.

```
[DataContract(Namespace="")]
public class VideoFrame
{
    [Key]
    public int VideoFrameId { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 0, IsRequired = false)]
    public int TimeStamp { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 1, IsRequired = false)]
    public string Base64EncodedFrame { get; set; }
}

[DataContract(Namespace = "")]
public class Video
{
    [Key]
    public int VideoId { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 0, IsRequired = false)]
    public virtual List<VideoFrame> VideoFrames { get; set; }
}

[DataContract(Namespace="")]
public class GeoLocation
{
    [Key]
    public int GeoLocationId { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 0, IsRequired = true)]
    public int TimeStamp { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 1, IsRequired = true)]
    public double Latitude { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 2, IsRequired = true)]
    public double Longitude { get; set; }
}

[DataContract(Name="root", Namespace="")]
public class DeviceUpdate
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    [DataMember (Order=0, IsRequired=true)]
    public string DeviceId { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    [DataMember(Order=1, IsRequired=true)]
    public int TimeStamp { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 2, IsRequired = true)]
    public virtual List<GeoLocation> GeoLocations { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 3, IsRequired = true)]
    public virtual List<Video> Videos { get; set; }
}
```

The web service code is:

```
DeviceUpdate dataObject = OperationContext.Current.RequestContext.RequestMessage.GetBody<DeviceUpdate>();
```

Webconfig:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="BugsBunny.RestService" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="BugsBunny.IRestService" behaviorConfiguration="web"></endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
  </system.webServer>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

This may help too, I pulled the actual XML that it is attempting to process after the JSON is revived:

```
<root type="object">
  <DeviceId type="string">74a5f7aa9d4dfd0d</DeviceId>
  <TimeStamp type="number">1394756724</TimeStamp>
  <GeoLocations type="array">
    <item type="object">
      <TimeStamp type="number">1394756724</TimeStamp>
      <Latitude type="number">948.348275</Latitude>
      <Longitude type="number">381.3252</Longitude>
    </item>
    <item type="object">
      <TimeStamp type="number">1394756726</TimeStamp>
      <Latitude type="number">98.348275</Latitude>
      <Longitude type="number">31.3252</Longitude>
    </item>
  </GeoLocations>
  <Videos type="array">
    <item type="object">
      <VideoFrames type="array">
        <item type="object">
          <TimeStamp type="number">1234567789</TimeStamp>
          <Base64EncodedFrame type="string">dajflahfaskfasld</Base64EncodedFrame>
        </item>
        <item type="object">
          <TimeStamp type="number">1234567789</TimeStamp>
          <Base64EncodedFrame type="string">dajflahfaskfasld</Base64EncodedFrame>
        </item>
      </VideoFrames>
    </item>
  </Videos>
</root>
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok,  I have found a way to make this work.

I have changed the web-service implementation to this:

```
DeviceUpdate dataObject = OperationContext.Current.RequestContext.RequestMessage.GetBody<DeviceUpdate>(new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(DeviceUpdate)));
```

And added:

```
RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json
```

to the service interface attributes.

This allows all objects to populate in the data contact.

Thank you for everyone's help.

Answer (score 1):

Here you will not get the geo location because BodyStyle bare does not include the namespace while the wrapped does it so you can get the other properties also.

try this

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
    UriTemplate = "/json")]
String JSONData();
```

Comment: Great catch!  I looked over this code many times and just kept looking over that.  Unfortunately this was not enough to solve the problem.  GeoLocations is still empty.  I made the change to the OP as well.